# How to get user email from botbuilder with Skype for Business?

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype, skype-for-business

I'm using botbuilder package in a nodejs application and I need to get the user information from the Skype for Business channel, so that I can authorize against my custom authentication system - the username would work too.
Using session storage or anything like this doesn't work for my use case, so I need the actual user information.
How can I get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Skype for Business` channel, you will found the user email in the id field of the user.

- In Node.js: `session.message.address.user.id` field
- In C#: `activity.From.Id` field

It has the following format: `sip:mymail@mydomain.com`

Comment: thanks for the response, how do I get to this property? I'm using that BotUniversal, which by the way I don't know if it's correct

Comment: I don't know what you mean by BotUniversal

Comment: app.post('/messages', connector.listen());
const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
});

this is what I'm using as the trigger

Comment: `session.message.address.user.id`

Comment: I'm using the web chat to test this approach but it shows an id, not an email. Also, I have the hooks in a cloud function.

Comment: The Id have different formats given the channel so it's normal that you see an alphanumeric value in webchat

Comment: maybe that's the problem, I'll try to deploy skype for business again and give this another try, thanks Nicolas

Comment: You were right, Nicolas, when using Skype for Business it gets the correct email. Thank you very much!